# 'Technical effects' of software patents for eligibility

Tags: patentability, software, specification, european, drafting

For patent eligibility of software patents in many countries including EU there is a requirement of 'technical effects' on the hardware device. These 'technical effects' are technological advances or improvements to the hardware on which the software runs. Examples are - faster operation, lower memory requirements, better user interface, lower hard disk access etc.

For software patents, such 'technical effects' need to be listed in the claims section or the detailed specifications? The point being that the claims section might be worded as a method. The 'technical effects' benefits of this method could be listed in detailed specifications. Or for patent eligibility, even the claims should be worded so as to keep the focus primarily on these 'technical effects'?